# CRM 2013 Unintended Nested Iframes

Tags: html, iframe, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm working in CRM 2013. A business requirement was to add a dashboard as a subarea to the site-map. I added the sub-area with an html web-resource added to put the appropriate dashboard in an IFrame.

The problem occurs when I try to open one the activity record in the IFrame's sub-grid. The IFrame creates another IFrame within itself (the Iframes nest). Below is my HTML and a screenshot of the issue.

```
<html>
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe name="dashboardIframe" title="Content Area" id="dashboardIframe" src="about:blank" style="border: 0px currentColor; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; right: 0px; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible;"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var openMyActivities = function () {
    var serverUrl = document.domain;
    var dashboardUrl = "https://" + serverUrl + "/dashboards/dashboard.aspx?dashboardId=%7b88dada11-007f-e311-940b-005056b72da0%7d&dashboardType=1030&pagemode=iframe";
    document.getElementById("dashboardIframe").src = dashboardUrl;
};
    window.onload = setTimeout(openMyActivities, 10);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to post a picture of the nested IFrame issue, but because I'm new to contributing to StackOverflow so I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Could you please try to use `parent.document` instead of just `document`? It should refer not to IFrame itself, but the document holding it.

Answer (score 0):

As it creates nested IFrames,
the only way to pick up the target iframe having id `dashboardIframe` is as follows.

```
var mainFrame = window.top.document.getElementById('contentIFrame0').contentDocument.frames["dashboardFrame"];

var targetIframe = mainFrame.document.frames["dashboardIframe"];
```

> Where contentIFrame0 is created by default in CRM when we insert an IFRAME component in dashboard area.